# EventToCommand binding with parameters in portable view models

Tags: xaml, viewmodel, mvvmcross, portable-class-library, eventtocommand

I am implementing a view model that is shared by applications on multiple platforms. I am using MvvmCross v3 that has its own MvxEventToCommand class, but I believe the challenge is the same for other frameworks like MVVM Light. As long as the event is used without parameters, the implementation is straightworward, and this is the case for simple interactions like tapping the control.

But when the command needs to handle event arguments things become more complicated. For example, the view model needs to act on certain scroll bar changes (and load more items in the associated list view). Here is the example of XAML:

```
<cmd:EventToCommand 
    Command="{Binding ScrollChanged}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding EventArgs}" />
```

(MvvmCross uses MvxEventToCommand, but the principle is the same).

Then in my model I can have the following command handler:

```
public ICommand ScrollChanged
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand<ScrollChangedEventArgs>(e =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Change!");
        });
    }
}
```

(MvxCommand in MvvmCross).

The problem is that ScrollChangedEventArgs is platform specific and this code simply will not compile in a portable class library. This is a general problem with any command that needs not only a push when an event was fired but requires more specific event details. Moving this code in platform-specific part is silly because it more or less kills the concept of portable view models and code-behind-free views. I tried to search for projects that share view models between different platforms, but they all use simple events like "Tap" with no attached event details.

**UPDATE 1** I agree with Stuart's remark that view models should only deal with higher level abstractions, so I will rephrase the original concern: how to map results of low-level interactions to a platform-neutral event that triggers a business logic command? Consider the example above: the business logic command is "load more items in a list", i.e. we deal with a list virtualization where a limited number of items from a large collection are loaded initially, and scrolling down to a bottom of a list should cause additional items to be loaded.

WinRT can take care of list virtualization by using observable collections that support ISupportIncrementalLoading interface. The runtime detects this capability and automatically requests extra items from a respective service when the user scrolls down the list. On other platforms this feature should be implemented manually and I can't find any other way than reacting on ScrollViewer ScrollChanged event. I can see then two further options:

- Place OnScrollChanged handler in a code-behind file and call the portable view model higher level event (such as "OnItemsRequested");
- Avoid code-behind stuff and struggle to wire the ScrollChanged event directly to a view model, then we will need to remap the platform-specific event first.

As long as there is no support for second option, putting event handler in code-behind file is OK as long as it is done for the sole purpose of event mapping. But I would like to investigate what can be done using the second option. MvvmCross has MapCommandParameter class which seems to be able to help, so I wonder if I should exploit that one.

**UPDATE 2** I tried MapCommandParameter approach, and it worked allowing me to insert a platform-specific adapter that would map low-level events to view model-specific commands. So the second option worked without any struggle. Stuart also suggested listview-subclassing so there is no need to care about scrolling events. I plan to play with it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that viewmodel commands should normally be expressed in terms of viewmodel concepts - so it would be 'strange' to send the viewmodel a command about the scrollbar value changing, but it might be ok to send the viewmodel a command about the user selecting certain list elements to be visible (which she does via scrolling)

One example where I've done this type of thing previously is in list selection.

I originally did this across multiple platforms using a cross-platform eventargs object -

- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/Commands/MvxSimpleSelectionChangedEventArgs.cs

this was then used on WindowsPhone (for example) via an EventToCommand class like https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone/Commands/MvxSelectionChangedEventToCommand.cs

However... I have to admit that this code hasn't been used much... For list selection we have instead mainly used selecteditem binding, and there simply haven't been any apps that have needed more complex parameterized commands (so far) - you might even need to go back to very old v1 mvvmcross code to find any samples that use it.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart, I have extended the post with how I understand this can be achieved. Basically it's a choice between putting event mappers in code-behind or using MvvmCross MapCommandParameter class. I fully agree that platform specific event details don't belong to a view model.

Comment: Can't answer - plane takeoff time. But for load more, consider subclassing listview so that it can fire the loadmorecommand rather than working off of scrolling events. I think this is roughly what the tutorial pulltorefresh does

Comment: I will try both options, just to see what looks cleaner. Thanks for the suggestions.